# Best way to update my django model coming from an external api source?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I am getting my data through requesting an api source, then I put it in my django model. However, data update daily.. so how can I update these data without rendering it everytime?

```
def index (request):
    session = requests.Session()
    df = session.get('https://api.coincap.io/v2/assets')
    response= df.json()
    coin = response['data']
    final_result = coin.to_dict('records')
    for coin in final_result:
        obj, created = Coincap.objects.update_or_create(
            symbol = coin['symbol'],
            name = coin['name'],
            defaults = {
                'price': coin['priceUsd']
                })
    return render(request, '/home.html/')
```

Right now, I have to go to `/home.html` , if I want my data update. However, my goal is to later serialize it and make it REST api data, so I wouldn't touch django template anymore. Anyway for it to update internally once a day after i do `manage.py runserver`?

Comment: Seems like it should be a periodic task. You can use either a cronjob or [celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/index.html) to do the update.

Comment: You can use crontab for this purpose and for Django you can use [django-crontab](https://pypi.org/project/django-crontab/) to can call your views periodically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple and common solution is to create a [custom Django admin command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-management-commands/#management-commands-and-locales) and use [Cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) to run it at specified intervals. You can write a command's code to your liking and it can have access to all of the models, settings and other parts of your Django project.

You would put your code making a request and writing data to the DB, using your Django models, in your new `Command` class's `handle()` method (obviously `request` parameter is no longer needed). And then, if for example you have named your command `update_some_data`, you can run it as `python manage.py update_some_data`.

Assuming Cron exists and is running on the machine. Then you could setup Cron to run this command for you at specified intervals, for example create a file `/etc/cron.d/your_app_name` and put

```
0 4 * * * www-data /usr/local/bin/python /path/to/your/manage.py update_some_data >> /var/log/update_some_data.log  2>&1
```

This would make your update be done everyday at 04:00. If your command would provide any output, it will be written to `/var/log/update_some_data.log` file.
Of course this is just an example, so your server user running your app (`www-data` here) and path to the Python executable on the server (`/usr/local/bin/python` here) should be adjusted for particular use.

See links for further guidance.

Answer (score 5):

For those that are looking for an example:

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self,*args,**kwargs):
        //Your request api here
        for coin in final_result:
            obj, created = Coincap.objects.update_or_create(
                symbol = coin['symbol'],
                name = coin['name'],
                defaults = {
                    'price': coin['priceUsd']})
```

Then you run in with cron just as Nikita suggested.

Comment: If, for some reason, your custom management command must run without an active locale (for example, to prevent translated content from being inserted into the database), deactivate translations using the `@no_translations` decorator on your `handle()` method: