# Is there a way to update an object's specific field using an api in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

Apologies if my question seems a bit basic, or too complicated, but I'm still learning django.

What I'd like to do is somehow update a model object's field, preferably using an api call. I'll try to demonstrate.

I have several different model objects that look like this.

```
class Quarterback(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)  
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    score = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

I'd like to know if it's possible to populate the "score" field with data pulled via an api url. Of course, I can populate the score manually, or with an event listener like onclick, but because scores are dynamic and change every week, I'd really like to find a way to have the score field populate via the api because their data updates each week. At the moment, I'm displaying individual scores in my html by comparing the player's name in the model shown above with a list of names and scores stored in a variable that gets its info from the api. If I could somehow get the "score" field of this model to get its info from the url/api, I could just iterate through the object and display the score very easily.

Even if this is completely impossible, I appreciate anyone telling me so as I have no idea.

Comment: You can use normal update view api for this.

Comment: Would that be a function that goes into the object/class, or would it be a function in views.py?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53293461/best-way-to-update-my-django-model-coming-from-an-external-api-source

Comment: @Txema It does a bit. Thanks!